# Set a fixed size of memory of a debugger session

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Is it possible to start a debug session in a Winforms project in Visual Studio and set a fixed size of memory which the process can have?

Let's say for example I have 16GB of memory in my machine, now I want to test my program for `OutOfMemory` Exceptions... And I can't load so much data that my 16GB are full. So I want to set my debug session that my programm can only use 2GB and than it throws 
`OutOfMemory` Exceptions.

Is this even possible?

Or do I need some VirtualMachine which were I can set it?